# Parse sequence of similar blocks as Map<String, Type>

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

Consider I have such `json` fragment (part of more complex json):

```
"foo": {
    "abc": {
        "prop1": "blabla11";
        "prop2": "blabla12";
        "prop3": "blabla13";
     },
     "bcd": {
        "prop1": "blabla21";
        "prop2": "blabla22";
        "prop3": "blabla23";
     },
     ... 
}
```

I.e. all `abc`, `bcd` and so on items have same internal structure.

Is any elegant way to annotate following `java` structure in order parse it via `jackson` to object of `Foo` class?

**Notice:** `foo` isn't root structure, so I can not parse it separately.

```
public class Foo {       
    private Map<String, FooItem> items;   
    ...        
}

public class FooItem {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a larger structure which you can use to read in the more complex JSON.  Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to ignore any unknown bits.

Try this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LargerStructure {

    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}


public class App {

    public static void main(String ...args){

        File input = new File("largerInput.json");
        LargerStructure largerStructure = deserialise(input);
        System.out.println(largerStructure.getFoo());
    }


    public static LargerStructure deserialise(File input){

        LargerStructure largerStructure = null;

        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            largerStructure = mapper.readValue(input, LargerStructure.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return largerStructure;
    }
}
```

Comment: How this will help me parse `Foo`'s structure as `Map<String, FooItem>`?

Comment: Your question was on how to parse the fragment to a Foo object, where the foo element was not the root.  The code in the answer will do that.  If you're still having trouble, ensure you've got the correct accessor methods for the member variables on the Foo and FooItem classes.

Comment: Will it fill map `Map<String, FooItem>`? Did you tried it?

Comment: My dear, you've read question very inattentive and didn't got its essential. You answer is simply doesn't work on my example.

Comment: First, thanks for the down vote.  That's a great way to thank someone trying to help you.  Second, the code works fine.  I've successfully run it with a fragment like the one you described.  I've created a repo on GitHub as a more complete example https://github.com/gamanoju/JacksonParser